# jQuery Deferred/promise not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so I've read 1,000,000+ articles on jQuery deferreds and/or promises, and I'm still getting something wrong.

```
functionOne() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/mypath/etc'
    });

    request.done(function(data) {

        // TODO: I've got stuff here that takes a while.

        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}

functionTwo() {
    // Something that depends on the others being finished.
}

$.when(
    functionOne(), 
    anotherLongRunningFunctionWithAjax())
 .then(
    functionTwo()
);
```

I need any function(s) in the "when" to fully complete (.ajax done) before the "then" starts. However, the promise returns immediately (as expected), but functionTwo starts, even though functionOne has not called "done".

I'm sure it's a fundamental misunderstanding of deferred and the chain-of-calls.

Edit:

```
function functionOne() {
    console.log('functionOne called');

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/mypath/etc'
    });

    request.done(function(data) {
        console.log('Starting Done.');

        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('Done finished.');
        }, 5000);
    });

    console.log('Returning promise.');
    return request;
}

function functionTwo() {
    console.log('functionTwo called');
}

$.when(functionOne()).then(functionTwo());
```

Gives me this in the console:

```
functionOne called
Returning promise.
functionTwo called (should be called after Done is finished.)
Starting Done.
Done finished.
```

Comment: `var deferred = $.Deferred();` unnecesary, you already get one from $.ajax. Chain off of it with .then.

Comment: Your logic as-is should work, my guess is the `// TODO:` sections actually have code in them and aren't delaying the .resolve() call properly.

Comment: @KevinB Quite honestly, I tried it without the additional $.Deferred first, but I couldn't get that to work either. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Your new code after update will not delay function 2 on function 1's setTimeout completion, that's by design. For that functionality, you'd have to use .then rather than .done and create a new promise to return to the .then that resolves when the setTimeout completes. Additionally, $.when isn't needed for a single promise, but it doesn't necessarily hurt either.

Comment: @KevinB But whether I'm using setTimeout or something else, wouldn't the "Starting done" at least occur? I'm not actually using a setTimeout, but loading a dropdown. In fact, you can completely comment-out the setTimeout, and the "Starting done" is still occuring last.

Comment: well, no, because .done() doesn't alter the promise, it just attaches a callback to it. callbacks are first in first out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the code in your edit, there are two issues:

1. The timer in *functionOne* starts after *request* is resolved, yet you return *request*. So whatever happens with the timer... it is of not relevance to the returned promise, which at that time is already resolved.
2. You call *functionTwo* immediately, instead of passing the function reference for the *$.when* promise to call back

Here is working code:

```js
function functionOne() {
    console.log('functionOne called');
    console.log('Returning promise.');
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log('Starting Done.');
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('Done finished.');
            dfd.resolve(data); // indicate when you are done
        }, 2000); // 2 seconds will do ;-)
        return dfd.promise(); // you need to return a promise again
    });
}

function functionTwo() {
    console.log('functionTwo called');
}

// don't call functionTwo immediately, leave that to the promise to do:
$.when(functionOne()).then(functionTwo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, for future reference (for myself): If I add parenthesis to functionTwo in "then" (e.g. .then(function())), the function will still fire immediately. Therefore, if params are needed in functionTwo, create a var holding the function pointer. e.g. var f2 = function() { functionTwo(param); } and pass the pointer to ".then(f2)". Or, .then(function() { functionTwo(param); });

Comment: For adding parameters, you can also use `bind`: `.then(functionTwo.bind(null, param))`.

Answer (score 1):

you are [using an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) since `$.ajax` itself returns a promise

Just do

```
functionOne() {

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/mypath/etc'
    });

    request.done(function(data) {
        // TODO: I've got stuff here that takes a while.       
    });

    return request
}
```

Comment: Without knowing what *"I've got stuff here that takes a while"* does it is hard to help more

Comment: I get a down-vote for asking? I asked because I didn't understand.